# Prove that Gamma function is divergent for $\Re(z)\leq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, divergent-integrals

How can I prove by definition that the Gamma function
$$
\Gamma(z):=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z-1} \ dt
$$
is divergent for $\Re(z)\leq 0$. I can prove it for real $z\leq 0$ only.
Thanks!

Comment: If $\Re z<0$, then $z=a+ib$ with $a<0$ and $t^{z-1}=\exp((z-1)\log(t)=\exp((a-1)\log(t))\cdot\exp(ib\log(t))=t^{a-1}g(t)$, where $g(t)=\exp(ib\log(t))$ and $|g(t)|=1$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Why? Based on what ? Looks like you have not done any work or spent anytime on this , maybe go Google it at least

Comment: Dear Jean-Claude! It's ok, thank you, but how to continue?

Dear jimjim! I wrote here this question, because I need help. A checked this in many books, but I couldn't find any proof, just as I didn’t find anything helpful on the net either. I didn't want to make jokes or make anybody upset. I hope if someone knows some tips or the answer, then he/she will help. Maybe you misunderstand my question, my question is: can you show why this improper integral diverges for Re(z)=<0?

Comment: The *only* problem is the integral near $t=0$: for $c>0$, $\int_c^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt$ is absolutely convergent for every complex number $z$. Therefore just focus on $\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,dt$, or an integral from $0$ to $\varepsilon$ for your favorite positive number $\varepsilon$. Since $e^{-t} - 1 = O(t)$ for $t$ near $0$, show you can replace the factor $e^{-t}$ in the integral with $1$ to determine convergence or divergence of the integral from $0$ to $1$ (or $0$ to $\varepsilon$).

Comment: Thank you! I think, I found the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417305/showing-that-the-gammaz-improper-integral-diverges-for-operatornamere-z